# 404 Error when hosting asp.net webapi project in production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am building a simple webapi which retrieves customers balance from db.Everthing works well locally hosted in IIS.But when i host it with a subdomain i get 404 error.In IIS if i give the binding to localhost it works but changing to subdomain like this does not.

With sub-domain doesnot work.

> http://api.mydomain.com/v1/accounts/balance?accountNumber=CS-00001

With localhost it works.

> http://localhost/v1/accounts/balance?accountNumber=CS-00001

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("balance")]
    public string Getbalance(string accountNumber)
    {
        var data = BusinessLayer.Api.AccountHolderApi.GetBalance(accountNumber);

        return data;
    }
```

Route

`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("TestApi", "v1/{controller}/{action}");`

To test i added index.html to the root of the application, and it did showed up in browser.

Test Link

> http://api.mydomain.com/index.html

But calling the api with subdomain with action and controller gives 404 error.
My server is windows server 2008r2.

What i am doing wrong?Help Please

Comment: MVC does not use subdomains for routing by default. I recommend you to check 2 things. First: modify your hosts file and place api.mydomain.com to use 127.0.0.1 so you can test the 'production' domain on your develop machine. Add the binding in your local IIS. It should work. Secondly. check if the target version of the .net framework is installed on your 2008r2 server.

Comment: @NicoLubbers hello sir..in my local machine instead of localhost i added 127.0.0.1 and it worked..NET framework 4 is installed on my 2008r2 server and this webapi is built on .netframework 4.5.2.However on the same server i have a different asp.net project built in 4.5.2 framework but works well on this windows server 2008r2 machine.

Comment: @NicoLubbers i just installed .net framework 4.5.2 in my 2008r2 server.